# Ruby on Rails: Advanced search with two string in one search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble understanding advanced search with two string
pls help

error coms like:

> undefined method `where' for #
>
> ```
> <ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x007f2dcc0da5b0>
> ```

in the search model

search.rb

```
def search_books
  books = Book.all
  books = books.where{["name LIKE ?","%#{keywords}%"]}if keywords.present?
  books = books.where{["category LIKE ?","%#{keywords}%"]}if keywords.present?

  return books
end
```

Comment: It seems like your first query is returning nil.  can you log the output of your first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like the below:

> keywords = 'test'

with AND:

```
Book.where("name LIKE '%#{keywords}%' AND category LIKE '%#{keywords}%'") if keywords.present?
```

with OR:

```
Book.where("name LIKE '%#{keywords}%' OR category LIKE '%#{keywords}%'") if keywords.present?
```

But this usage is not safe. Read following warning from Rails [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html):

> Building your own conditions as pure strings can leave you vulnerable
>   to SQL injection exploits. For example, Client.where("first_name LIKE
>   '%#{params[:first_name]}%'") is not safe.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use a scope for searching you could do something like this in your controller

```
    def index     
      @books = Book.all

      # scopes
      if params[:keyword].present? 
        @books = @books.by_keyword(params[:keyword])
      end
   end
```

then in your model do the below

```
  scope :by_keyword, ->(keyword) { where('name LIKE ? AND category LIKE ?', "%#{keyword}%", "%#{keyword}%").order(updated_at: :desc) if keyword.present? }
```